# Asp.net 3.5 Deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-3.5, iis-5

For deploying my website in server by using IIS 5.1,,i created virtual directory,,i browsed in to my application and selected
asp.net 2.0 tab(application is framework3.5)..I reset framwork configuratio 2,0 Runtime security Policy Enterprise,Machine,User
tab,,What ever things i can do i did

Still also application is working properly,,but i am not able to deploy it in IIS

i am getting this error

If i browse Login.aspx i am getting

**

```
Server Application Unavailable
The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.
Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
```

**

Is it with IIS 5.1??

***Here my machine is acting as server ,It has xp professional 2002 service pack 2 and IIS 5.1***

***Any body knows how to create application pool in IIS 5.1***

Comment: Any body knows how to create application pool in IIS 5.1

Comment: how can i install iis7 on windows xp SP2 which has already
iis5.1,,because i installed iis7 i can see on control panel
Add/remove section,,but in administrative tool side

iis is still 5.1 ,,i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can ... [Creating Application Pools in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525832%28VS.90%29.aspx)

> IIS 5.1 and earlier:  The AppCreate3
>   method, the IIS WMI provider, and
>   Application pools are not available,
>   and therefore this topic does not
>   apply.

Comment: how can i install iis7 on windows xp SP2 which has already
iis5.1,,because i installed iis7 i can see on control panel
Add/remove section,,but in administrative tool side

iis is still 5.1 ,,i need help

Comment: No you can't download newer IIS versions. Windows server 2003 came with IIS 6, Vista/Windows 2008 comes with IIS 7, Windows 7 / 2008 r2 comes with IIS 7.5. You can run a virtual machine with one of these OS on using Virtual Pc - http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/